# rails setup with vagrant using jumpstartlabs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vagrant, postgresql-9.1

So I decided to start learning Ruby on rails, and was trying to set up an environment.

First time doing this so I followed all of these instructions [here](http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/topics/vagrant_setup.html).

But when I try to test it out, it doesn't work:

```
PG::InvalidParameterValue: ERROR:  encoding UTF8 does not match locale en_US
DETAIL:  The chosen LC_CTYPE setting requires encoding LATIN1.
: CREATE DATABASE "platform_validator_development" ENCODING = 'utf8'
```

What is going on? I was told to use UTF8 encoding in the directions. what is LATIN1 encoding? And how do I change to it?

Answer (score 3):

There is a missing step in the JumpstartLab's instructions. After setting the locale you need to also setup your environment to use it before `initdb` is run. The problem is in the "Locale" section of the [JumptartLab's instructions](http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/topics/vagrant_setup.html):

```
$ sudo /usr/sbin/update-locale LANG=en_GB.UTF-8 LC_ALL=en_GB.UTF-8  # I am in GB, you may want US
$ . /etc/default/locale    # missing step
```

Now check your locale (see "How did it happen?" below for what happens if you don't do the missing step)

```
$ locale          # look, UTF-8 encodings
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_GB.UTF-8
```

Now when you come to the section "Creating the Database Instance & Adding a User" the `initdb` command  (which they don't specify with a `--encoding=` argument) can work out the UTF-8 encoding from the environment. This makes it into the template1 database from which other databases are created. So it won't clash with the utf8 encoding specified by the `development` and `test` entries in platform_validator's `config/database.yml` which is read when you run `rake db:create`.

### Just make it go away

If you are reading this because you have already followed the JumpstartLab's instructions and hit a problem when running `rails db:create` then you will need to correct the setup of your Postgres installation in your VirtualBox. The problem is in the template1 database, from which all other databases are created.

Either correct template1 by `sudo su postgres` then `psql template1` then follow this [gist](https://gist.github.com/ebinion/5690817#file-gistfile1-txt) as described in this [blog](http://ezekielbinion.com/blog/making-rake-dbcreate-postgres-behave/).

Or more drastically, remove Postgres: `sudo apt-get --purge remove postgresql\*` then correct your locale and environment as above and re-do the JumpstartLab's instructions from "PostgreSQL Installation": `sudo apt-get install postgresql libpq-dev`.

### How did that happen?

The JumpstartLab's instructions lead you to install an Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 32-bit box. Before changing locale or installing Postgres, Ruby or Rails, start the box with `vagrant up` and connect to it with `vagrant ssh` and look at the locale settings. You see that the locale language is set to (en)glish and the territory US but there is no encoding, such as UTF-8 or LATIN1:

```
vagrant@precise32:~$ locale
LANG=en_US
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US"
LC_TIME="en_US"
LC_COLLATE="en_US"
LC_MONETARY="en_US"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US"
LC_PAPER="en_US"
LC_NAME="en_US"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US"
LC_ALL=en_US
```

So when you install Postgres it gets no direction from its host about encoding and unfortunately defaults to LATIN1 rather than UTF-8. The JumpstartLab's instructions make you think you have set the locale:

```
vagrant@precise32:~$ sudo /usr/sbin/update-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

but you haven't:

```
vagrant@precise32:~$ locale  # should login again or source /etc/default/locale before doing this
LANG=en_US
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US"
LC_TIME="en_US"
LC_COLLATE="en_US"
LC_MONETARY="en_US"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US"
LC_PAPER="en_US"
LC_NAME="en_US"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US"
LC_ALL=en_US
vagrant@precise32:~$
```

so when you now install Postgres you get its default LATIN1 encoding for template1:

```
vagrant@precise32:/vagrant$ psql -l
                             List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding | Collate | Ctype |   Access privileges
-----------+----------+----------+---------+-------+-----------------------
 postgres  | postgres | LATIN1   | en_US   | en_US |
 template0 | postgres | LATIN1   | en_US   | en_US | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |         |       | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | LATIN1   | en_US   | en_US | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |         |       | postgres=CTc/postgres
(3 rows)
```

This clashes with the utf8 encoding specified by the `development` and `test` entries in platform_validator's `config/database.yml` which is used when you run `rake db:create`.

Comment: This answer solved my problem in a general Rails install on Debian 8 jessie, nothing to do with vagrant or jumpstartlabs.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
sudo su postgres

psql

update pg_database set datistemplate=false where datname='template1';
drop database Template1;
create database template1 with owner=postgres encoding='UTF-8'
  lc_collate='en_US.utf8' lc_ctype='en_US.utf8' template template0;

update pg_database set datistemplate=true where datname='template1';
```

The problem was that the encoding of the template1 is latin for default and the configuration set up is en_US or en_GB.

Hope it helps